# Run Makefile with crontab

Tags: postgresql, makefile, cron, osmosis

I'm new in Ubuntu and programming.
I'm testing a program that I found on github, to download and import OSM data into postgis.
It works when I run it from terminal (url and name are fake):

```bash
make all NAME=dbname URL='http://myurl'
```

using postgres user.

Now I need to run this command every day.
So I wrote that script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# go to the directory with Makefile
cd /PCuserhome/directory/to/Makefile/

# run Makefile
make all NAME=dbname URL='http://myurl'
```

and it works when i run it from terminal.

So I have added it to crontab (of postgres user) in this way:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /PCuserhome/myscript.sh
```

It create the db but probably fail in running osmosis selection (Osmosis is in the path for all users).
Any idea to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

crontab commands are executed only with minimal environment variables, i.e.

`PATH=/usr/bin:/bin` (on debian anyway),

so if you are relying on programs that are in your `$PATH`, it will fail.
Consider specifying an absolute path to the osmosis program wherever it's called from.

Alternatively you can change `$PATH` itself in your script

```
export PATH="/my/bin:$PATH"
```

---

p.s.: you can check the environment by adding a simple cron job

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.txt
```